# Javascript Conflict Causing Hidden Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, conflict

I am having a conflict between these two bits of Javascript on the same page. If the navigation js(a) is loaded onto the page with the other js(b) it causes the elements created by js(b) to be hidden. I have properly loaded the navigation mmenu plugin for js(a) and it is working but it seems to cause js(b) to no longer be able to create html.
I know that it is js(a) that causes this conflict because when I take it out or disable the external js of the mmenu plugin it allows js(b) to create html properly again.

```
js(a)
<script>
$(function() {
       $("#my-menu").mmenu({
           // options object
        }, {
           // configuration object
     });
 });
</script>

js(b)
  <script type="text/javascript">             
           if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("yes") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="' + location.pathname + '-free-sample" class="button Sample">Click to Order a Free Sample</a>');
                }

            else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("chsample") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="' + location.pathname + '-sample" class="button Sample">Click to Order a Sample</a>');
                }
            else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("quote") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/quick_quote_form.htm" class="button Sample" target="_blank">Click to Request a Price Quote</a>');
                }
           else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("sam_quo") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="' + location.pathname + '-free-sample" class="button Sample" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Click to Order a Free Sample</a><a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/quick_quote_form.htm" class="button Sample" target="_blank">Click to Request a Price Quote</a>');
                }
           else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("swa_quo") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/form.html" class="button Sample" style="margin-bottom:10px;" target="_blank">Click to Order a Free Sample</a><a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/quick_quote_form.htm" class="button Sample" target="_blank">Click to Request a Price Quote</a>');
                }

           else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("simsol1") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
          $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/products/simple-solution-i-peel-stick-carpet-tiles.html-free-sample" class="button Sample">Click to Order a Free Sample</a>');
                }

           else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("simsol2") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/products/simple-solution-ii-peel-stick-carpet-tiles.html-free-sample" class="button Sample">Click to Order a Free Sample</a>');
                }
           else if ($('.FreeSample h3').html().indexOf("swatch") >= 0)
                 {
                    $('.FreeSample h3').html('');
                    $('.FreeSampleLink').html('<a href="http://www.georgiacarpet.com/form.html" class="button Sample" target="_blank">Click to Order a Free Sample</a>');
                }

             else {
                 $('.FreeSample').remove();
                 };
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you included the mmenu plugin?

Comment: Yes, the plugin works but when it is working it causes js(b) to no longer create html properly.

Comment: Console errors? How are the elements "hidden"? Do they appear in the page code?

Comment: No the elements written by the js(b) do not appear in page code though I do see them get created briefly when the page first loads but they immediately become either hidden or cease to exist when js(b) is broken by js(a).